# What's the relationship between metadata and data model?

Tags: database, database-design, metadata, data-modeling, datamodel

Is is appropriate to consider metadata as the instance of data model?

I am sure that in relational DBMS, foreign key is part of its data model, and the specification of foreign key is kind of metadata. But I found no evidence that `is instance of` relationship is **universal** between these 2 concepts.

BTW, I've already refered some text books like Database System Concepts and Fundamentals of Database Systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata is data that expresses a data model.  An example is the data dictionary that accompanies the schema in most database systems.  The advantage of this way of expressing a model is that the same query language that is used to examine the data can be used on the metadata.